# Discord Api doesn't send events anymore after first heartbeat sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, discord, heartbeat

I've got a problem, when I start my bot, all commands work, but when I send the first heartbeat, the Discord Api doesn't send me events anymore.
My code:

```js
botToken = token;

    const ws = new WebSocket("wss://gateway.discord.gg/?v=6&encoding=json");

    let interval = 0;
    let session_id;
    let last_seq;
    let payload = {
      op: 2,
      d: {
        token: botToken,
        intents: 32767,
        properties: {
          $os: "linux",
          $browser: "chrome",
          $device: "chrome",
        },
      },
    };

    ws.on("open", function open() {
      ws.send(JSON.stringify(payload));
    });

    ws.on("message", function incoming(data) {
      let response = JSON.parse(data);
      const { t, event, op, d, s } = response;

      last_seq = s;

      switch (op) {
        case 10:
          const { heartbeat_interval } = d;
          interval = heartbeat(heartbeat_interval);
        break;
        case 7:
          ws.send(JSON.stringify({
            op: 6, 
            d: {
              token: botToken,
              session_id: session_id,
              last_seq: s
            } 
          })) 
        break;
      }

      if(t == "READY") {
        session_id = d.session_id;
        console.log("session id: " + session_id)
      }
      let eventName = t + "Callback";
      console.log(t)
      if(callbacks[eventName]) {
        if (typeof callbacks[eventName] == "function") {
          callbacks[eventName](d);
        }
      }
    });

    const heartbeat = (ms) => {
      return setInterval(() => {
        console.log("heartbeat sent")
        ws.send(JSON.stringify({ op: 3, d: last_seq }));
      }, ms);
    };
```

Console output:
[image: Console output:]
As you can see, after "heartbeat sent" I don't receive events anymore.
Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to make an attempt at responding to your question.

By what I'm seeing I believe your opcode is to be "1" rather than "3", if I am correct any wrong data kills the connection from the ws and this could be why you don't receive any updates.

I also took a look at your code and there is no error handling for if the ws runs into an error or disconnects, this could potentially also explain why there's no more events.

This is my take on the wss connection (Done in ahk):

```
__SendHeartbeat() {
  ;if !this
  heartbeat := {}
  heartbeat.op := this.NoQuote(1)
  heartbeat.d := this.NoQuote(this.Seq)
  this.__Send_Websocket(heartbeat)
}
```